# Where are an UIWebView's cookies stored?

Tags: iphone, cookies

I'm building an iPhone app with cookies. Deleting cookies in the Safari settings doesn't delete them. Where are they stored? Is it possible to read them from another UIWebView?

Thanks!

Answer (score 171, accepted):

Your application has its own "cookie jar" in the `[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]` container.

Here's how you might take a quick look at the cookies in your application's cookie jar:

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieJar = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [cookieJar cookies]) {
   NSLog(@"%@", cookie);
}
```

Several methods are available for filtering and manipulation. Take a look at the [NSHTTPCookieStorage](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation for accessing cookies, and the [NSHTTPCookie](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookie_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation for accessing individual cookie properties.

Comment: That's interesting.  I didn't know such a thing existed.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: That's great! How do I log a specific cookie for a specific server?

Comment: To get cookies for a specific server, use the `cookiesForURL` method instead of `cookies`

Comment: @Hamutsi: See the `-cookiesForURL:` instance method in the `NSHTTPCookieStorage` class. Read the documentation link for more info.

Comment: This method doesn't really work because this will only delete the cookies until you quit the app. But when you reopen it cookies will still be there.

Comment: @AlexReynolds sorry to bug, but this isn't quite a full question for SO yet: can those cookies be accessed (perhaps they just are) by any  `NSURLConnection` instance? I need to have a user authenticate with a `UIWebView` first, then I want to switch to Web Services.

Comment: Yes, they are available and passed along with subsequent requests. However, you will want to check the lifespan between app sessions.

Comment: Can I prevent this "cookie jar" to being create? I mean, I don't want to create any cookies for my UIWebView. Can I do that?

Comment: I have small question that is, what will happen if i don't remove cookies from webview? Will it affect app size or Will appstore people allow that thing?

Comment: Here's another question that answers how to clear the UIWebView cache in ObjC and Swift: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468553/clearing-uiwebview-cache

Answer (score 21):

Thanks for the pointer Alex! To add to this I will drop in my "cookie dumper" that I created using Alex's example. Maybe this will help someone else.

```
- (void) dumpCookies:(NSString *)msgOrNil {
NSMutableString *cookieDescs    = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieJar = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [cookieJar cookies]) {
    [cookieDescs appendString:[self cookieDescription:cookie]];
}
NSLog(@"------ [Cookie Dump: %@] ---------\n%@", msgOrNil, cookieDescs);
NSLog(@"----------------------------------");
}

- (NSString *) cookieDescription:(NSHTTPCookie *)cookie {

NSMutableString *cDesc      = [[[NSMutableString alloc] init] autorelease];
[cDesc appendString:@"[NSHTTPCookie]\n"];
[cDesc appendFormat:@"  name            = %@\n",            [[cookie name] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[cDesc appendFormat:@"  value           = %@\n",            [[cookie value] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[cDesc appendFormat:@"  domain          = %@\n",            [cookie domain]];
[cDesc appendFormat:@"  path            = %@\n",            [cookie path]];
[cDesc appendFormat:@"  expiresDate     = %@\n",            [cookie expiresDate]];
[cDesc appendFormat:@"  sessionOnly     = %d\n",            [cookie isSessionOnly]];
[cDesc appendFormat:@"  secure          = %d\n",            [cookie isSecure]];
[cDesc appendFormat:@"  comment         = %@\n",            [cookie comment]];
[cDesc appendFormat:@"  commentURL      = %@\n",            [cookie commentURL]];
[cDesc appendFormat:@"  version         = %d\n",            [cookie version]];

//  [cDesc appendFormat:@"  portList        = %@\n",            [cookie portList]];
//  [cDesc appendFormat:@"  properties      = %@\n",            [cookie properties]];

return cDesc;
}
```

Comment: You might even add this as a category to extend `NSHTTPCookieStorage`: http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html

Comment: +1 for extracting out the logic of how to display a cookie into a separate method! Even for such a small snippet, it helps!!

Comment: Thank you! There is a typo: [cookie version] is NSUInteger, so %d should be used.

Answer (score 3):

Alex had a great idea about putting this in a category.  Here's what I ended up using:

NSHTTPCookieStorage+Info.h

```objectivec
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSHTTPCookieStorage (Info)

+ (NSDictionary*) describeCookies;
+ (NSDictionary *) describeCookie:(NSHTTPCookie *)cookie;

@end
```

NSHTTPCookieStorage.m

```
@implementation NSHTTPCookieStorage (Info)

+ (NSDictionary*) describeCookies {
    NSMutableDictionary *descriptions = [NSMutableDictionary new];

    [[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSHTTPCookie* obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [descriptions setObject:[[self class] describeCookie:obj] forKey:[[obj name] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }];

    NSLog(@"Cookies:\n\n%@", descriptions);
    return descriptions;
}

+ (NSDictionary *) describeCookie:(NSHTTPCookie *)cookie {
    return @{@"value" : [[cookie value] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding],
         @"domain" : [cookie domain] ? [cookie domain]  : @"n/a",
         @"path" : [cookie path] ? [cookie path] : @"n/a",
         @"expiresDate" : [cookie expiresDate] ? [cookie expiresDate] : @"n/a",
         @"sessionOnly" : [cookie isSessionOnly] ? @1 : @0,
         @"secure" : [cookie isSecure] ? @1 : @0,
         @"comment" : [cookie comment] ? [cookie comment] : @"n/a",
         @"commentURL" : [cookie commentURL] ? [cookie commentURL] : @"n/a",
         @"version" : @([cookie version]) };

}

@end
```

Makes the output a bit more "JSON-y"...

Answer (score 1):

in `sandbox:Library->Cookies->Cookies.binarycookies`
but you can not open the `.binarycookie`s directly, you can run a script:

1. Download and install Python
2. Download [BinaryCookieReader.py](http://securitylearn.net/wp-content/uploads/tools/iOS/BinaryCookieReader.py)
3. Run "Python BinaryCookieReader.py" on the terminal

[image]

as you can see, output log contains detail cookies description