# iPhone login example

Tags: iphone, cocoa

I'm developing a simple application. The layout is:
when you open the application, a login screen appears.
After the user clicks on the button "login", the application sends the two fields (username and password) to a login.php. login.php is:

```
<form method="POST">

<label for="id_username">Username:</label>
<input id="id_username" type="text" name="username" maxlength="30" />
<label for="id_password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="id_password" />
<input type="submit" class="bigbutton" value="login"/>
</form>
```

If the login is correct the loginview disappears and a tabbar controller will appear.

How can I send the two fields username and password to my page.php? And how can I receive a cookie for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to place a form-based HTTP request, specifically use an instance of [`ASIFormDataRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#sending_a_form_post_with_ASIFormDataRequest). Use the [NSHTTPCookieStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771498/where-are-an-uiwebviews-cookies-stored/771545#771545) manager to populate and read app cookies.