# How to clear the Cookies in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, cookies, uiwebview

I am using the UIWebView to load the URL. I want to know how to clear the Cookies in that .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete all cookies of UIWebView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471629/how-to-delete-all-cookies-of-uiwebview)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can go through each cookie in the cookie jar and remove them.

[How to delete all cookies of UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471629/how-to-delete-all-cookies-of-uiwebview)

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [storage cookies]) 
{
   [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

Comment: Actually, I got this code when I googled. But implemented in wrong place. Now changed to proper place . It works. Thank you !!!

Answer (score 1):

```
NSHTTPCookie *cooki;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *data = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cooki in [data cookies]) {
   [data deleteCookie:cooki];
}
```