# How can load a home page always into UIWebview when application become active?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an application what is a web wrapper.

I need to display a login page from the server into `UIWebView` always when application become `active`.
I tried in many ways but always if the user is logged second page is displayed and not login page(i don't have access to source page from server).
`UIWebView` is made in `storyboard` and only from code I load the request

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringWithUrl];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                         timeoutInterval:20.0];
[self.viewWeb loadRequest:request];
```

Also I register the class for notification when application enter in background to destroy webview

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(resetInterfaceForCaseWhenApplicationBecomeInactive)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

And in method what is trigger by notification

```
  self.viewWeb.delegate = nil;
  self.viewWeb = nil;
```

I don't know what can do more to solve this. Any suggestion?

Comment: Looks like you need to remove cookies [see here how to do this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4471629/1403732

Comment: @sage444 yes, from the cookies was the problem, thanks.

Comment: please select answer to close this question

Answer (score 0):

This problem related to cookies that web server puts to authenticated users, removing them should fix the issue. I added link to solution in comment before.