# How can I logout using the new release of ADALiOS 2.1

Tags: ios, adal

Or how can I access internal default cache store?

How can I clear default cache store?

Thanks,

Jignesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ADAL iOS 2.1, three functions are provided for deleting token items in cache:

- (BOOL)removeItem:(nonnull ADTokenCacheItem *)item
           error:(ADAuthenticationError * __nullable __autoreleasing * __nullable)error;
- (BOOL)removeAllForClientId:(NSString * __nonnull)clientId
                     error:(ADAuthenticationError * __nullable __autoreleasing * __nullable)error;
- (BOOL)removeAllForUserId:(NSString * __nonnull)userId
                    clientId:(NSString * __nonnull)clientId
                       error:(ADAuthenticationError * __nullable __autoreleasing * __nullable)error;

You can take a look at the following file :)

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc/blob/master/ADAL/src/public/ios/ADKeychainTokenCache.h

Comment: Yes, but how do I get access to the default cache store so that I can use those functions? If I implement my own caching mechanism by entending ADKeychainTokenCache than it make sense. But how do I get the default cache store? So that I can clear it. Thanks.

Comment: @jpanchal [ADKeychainTokenCache new]; will let you get the default cache store. 
You can also call [[ADKeychainTokenCache alloc] initWithGroup:] if you need to specify a keychain group id. Besides, you can take a look at the test app in ADAL 2.1, it is a good example on how the APIs can be used :)

Comment: Awesome. That is exactly what I was looking for. It is not very intuitive to know that new instance of ADKeychainTokenCache gives the default store. I actually did see the sample app but couldn't find anything there for clearing default store or accessing default cache store. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The `+[ADKeychainTokenCache defaultKeychainCache]` API has since been added to make this more discoverable.