# How are cookies managed in iPhone apps?

Tags: iphone, cookies, tracking, ads

Are apps-cookies stored in separate per-app location, or shared throughout the device? Are third-party cookies allowed (read/write)? Are persistant cookies allowed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Your application has its own "cookie jar" in the `[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]` container.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771498/where-are-an-uiwebviews-cookies-stored/771545#771545) An application only has access to cookies it creates or destroys, within the usual application sandbox model that applies for documents and preferences, as well.

Comment: thanks for the answer! do you know if third party cookies works (advertising) ? or if they are blocked (as in safari) ?

Comment: If you have an advertising framework integrated in your application, that framework is part of your application and can access resources within the application's sandbox.