# How to read cookies in my application iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new in iphone i am developing a application which is read cookies. but how do this i do not know plz help me.

Comment: Just a note.. You cant access cookies that is created by other Applications because of the Sandbox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are an UIWebView's cookies stored?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771498/where-are-an-uiwebviews-cookies-stored)

Answer (score 3):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771498/where-are-an-uiwebviews-cookies-stored) on how to access cookies. You need to use the `[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]`:

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieJar = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [cookieJar cookies]) {
   NSLog(@"%@", cookie);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's pretty easy.  The code below should get you started.  In my case, I just needed the value in 'Set-Cookie' but you can inspect what is in the headerFields dictionary and pull what you need.  For more advanced cookies, you may need to pull a cookie and do some string parsing. All depends on what your service provides.

```
// get cookie data
NSDictionary *headerFields = [connection.response allHeaderFields];
NSString *customCookie = [headerFields valueForKey:@"Set-Cookie"];
```

Comment: When receiving headers with multiple "Set-Cookie" entries, the dictionary appears to be combined them (into a single dictionary item).  Are there safe parsing rules to separate them again?

Comment: I'm sure there are some parsing libraries out there or you write your own pretty quickly - I believe the format is always <variable>=<value>&<variable2>=<value2> - but I haven't explored too closely.  You could also check out NSHTTPCookieStorage for something that's more appropriate for your needs - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html