# What happens to cookies of webview on closing the application?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, session-cookies

i am using a webview in an app which has keep me signed in functionality like facebook app.so in order to implement i need that the cookie should be persistant.I just wanted to know whether **ios persists the cookie** by default when the app is closed or i need to save the **cookie manually before closing the app** to implement **keep me signed in** functionality.

any help would be deeply appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a `NSHTTPCookieStorage` object to manage the cookies.  The short answer to your question is to use `NSHTPPCookieStorage` which will distribute the shared instance.  You can use this instance to get/set cookie information.

Take a look at the Apple documentation for `NSHTTPCookieStorage`, as well as the following two posts:

[Where are an UIWebView's cookies stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771498/where-are-an-uiwebviews-cookies-stored)

http://blog.andrewpaulsimmons.com/2008/08/add-set-and-delete-cookies-in-uiwebview.html

These should get you started down the right track.

Comment: Pretty sure that cookies will not be shared across different apps using the NSHTTPCookieStorage shared instance.

Comment: @Danra, whoops I misinterpreted the Apple doc that states, "NSHTTPCookieStorage implements a singleton object (shared instance) that manages the shared cookie storage. These cookies are shared among all applications and are kept in sync cross-process." - good call will edit answer.

Comment: Yes and this sentence is followed by "iOS Note: Cookies are not shared among applications in iOS."... Nice documentation Apple... :)