# Changing cookie policy on UIWebView

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, safari, uiwebview

Is the policy on iOS UIWebview is to accept all cookies by default or to block them?

If it is to block, how would I change this policy?

Thanks

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cookie policy is managed by:

```
[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage].cookieAcceptPolicy
```

And the default value is:

```
NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyOnlyFromMainDocumentDomain
```

Which is, **to accept** cookies only from your main document domain (the domain of the currently opened html document).

The relevant enum is:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicy) {
    NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways,
    NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyNever,
    NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyOnlyFromMainDocumentDomain
};
```

Comment: Hi Alon - thanks for that. Does that mean that when the request is initially made and a cookie is stored - then, by default, that cookie will be in use during that session until the user closes the application?

Comment: Hi, you can see further details of the cookies life cycle and management here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273063

Comment: @Mike "Does that mean that when the request is initially made and a cookie is stored": Yes. "by default, that cookie will be in use during that session until the user closes the application": Yes, however the cookies will also remain after the user restarts the app.