# iOS Sharing cookies across different UIWebViews

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

Is it possible to share cookies across two different UIWebView instances. What I am trying is in an UIWebView I load a request and in the shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate method I check whether the request type is either UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked || UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted. If yes, I will present a new viewcontroller which has a new UIWebView added on top of it's view by passing the url captured in the shouldStartLoadWithRequest. Then I load the url passed in the new UIWebView. In this process the cookies are not passed across the UIWebViews. Can anyone tell me what is going wrong.

Answer (score 5):

all webviews within one app should have one shared cookie store. `[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]`

if that one isnt used by all web views inside ONE APP, something is wrong :)

---

as for sharing between apps: you can't. you are sandboxed!

Comment: try dumping the cookie store to see if the cookies are there ok :) >> cool script at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771498/where-are-an-uiwebviews-cookies-stored