# Worklight saml 2.0 SSO

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-mobilefirst, saml-2.0

I am using Worklight 6.0 and in this case testing with iOS7.

I'm trying to setup saml 2.0 SSO with Worklight and I seem to have succeeded, but I don't know how it works... At first, I have my app attempt to access my url like this:

```
WLJQ.ajax({
    url: 'url.com',
    type: 'GET',
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(result) {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

The request goes to success and returns me the url of the login page, which is correct because I haven't authenticated yet, but it does not display the login (as I intended).

Next I click a button to display a Native page (iOS) which is a UIWebView of url.com. This displays the login page via:

```
WL.NativePage.show('LoginController', backFromNativeLoginPage, params);
```

I log in successfully and see the contents of url.com that I expect. Then I return back to the non-native app via:

```
[NativePage showWebView:0];
```

Now that I'm back in the non-native code, I sent the same request above and I expect for it not to return the contents of url.com, but rather the login page because I have no headers attached to my request and I think the non-native code shouldn't have any knowledge of the cookies I may have made in the UIWebView.

My question is how does this work? Does my non-native part of worklight have knowledge of all the cookies that were created in the native code's UIWebView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start by saying my answer is partly based on speculation, but I think this is whats happening:

Since your Native page is using the a WebView and Cordova is also using the WebView, any headers and cookies that your Native page is using will be visible when you return from native since [cookies are shared across differet UIWebViews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578624/ios-sharing-cookies-across-different-uiwebviews).

If your native page was using the native URL request methods or some third party / open source mechanism for connecting to your backend server, then I would think that your non-native page would not be able to see the headers and cookies.

Comment: This seems to be the case! Before returning to my non-native code I deleted all my cookies and it no longer works. Thanks!